# Can you match one path to another path in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

If I draw two different paths and later decide I want the second path to be a perfect match of the first path (or vice versa), is there a built in way to do that?

Please don't ask why or what I'm doing or for screenshots etc. This is a general knowledge question. Is there an option or tool in Illustrator that would let you select a path you've already made and tell it to "match" another path? Or is copying the desired path the only way to make another one exactly like it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you copy <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a path and then do a paste <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it makes an identical copy.

Additionally, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> places the copy in the exact same position, overlaying the original path.

Comment: Thanks! But that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if I ALREADY have two DIFFERENT paths, can I make one identical to the other AFTER the fact? Or is copying to begin with the only way to have two identical paths?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with 2 already existing paths.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I figured it might not be possible since I couldn't find anything about it anywhere I read. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Maybe somebody else has a better idea, there are more informed people than me posting here :) I think this could be approached via scripting, maybe, but it would be overly complicated to attempt that with no scripting experience.

Comment: @NoNeed you can inject a paths data and replace a existing path with it. But its just a really convoluted way of copying a path. Surely any effect stack you have is rasy enough to transfer over.

Comment: Hi! How would I get a path's data to inject it into another one? It does sound convoluted but if it's possible to do native to Illustrator without scripting/plugins it'd be useful to know. (I'm using v 24)